# Net_Gearman access job_id from within worker function?

Tags: php, gearman, worker

I'm trying to access the job_id of the current job from within my worker function so I can save the result to memcached under a key that equals the current worker function. Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
   <?php

    class Net_Gearman_Job_Example1 extends Net_Gearman_Job_Common{

        public function run($arg){
            echo 'job_started' . PHP_EOL;

            var_dump($arg);


            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->library('memcached_library', 'memcached');


// RIGHT HERE I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW JOB_ID OF CURRENTLY RUNNING JOB

            $CI->memcached->add();



            sleep(2);

            //return array('result' => 'finished', 'output' => 'some_output');

        }
    }
```

Comment: apologies for the sloppy code, just a quick copy-paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, should have looks for this sooner. Net_Gearman_Job_Common has properties for $handle and $conn -- those were all I needed to do this.